# PCB routing around capacitors "snake style" possible electric disadvantages?

Tags: capacitor, pcb-design, routing

Is there any reason not to route the +12V and GND lines in a snaking pattern as shown with C7 + C11? From instinct I'd always route caps in parallel to power and gnd rails.

Top left near D1 is the power supply.

[image: snake wiring]

Comment: Any reason you are using traces instead of a ground pour?

Comment: No issues with that. No issues using 90 degree corners either.

Comment: @DKNguyen won't 90° corners not create problems in high-speed applications? (Not for the power rails)

Comment: @Horst It's very unlikely that you're doing anything high-speed enough where that will matter.

Comment: @Horst Nope. You would have to be at incrediblly high frequencies before you begin to see its effects. Source: Lee Ritchey.

Comment: The angles look prettier though

Comment: Even if you just want to route "one layer" just save yourself the hassle and use the back for a ground pour. Basic element of PCB fab is just a core, it comes with copper on both sides anyway. Even if you are DIY, a ground pour is easy to register and etch at home. Perf boards are sold with ground pours on back also. The only reason not to is creepage for High Voltage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the obvious thing to do is make a ground plane and stop worrying about this sort of thing ;)

Since you probably don't want to do that, that ground stub is unlikely to hurt anything. However, I'd suggest getting rid of the stub, bringing +12 in a bit to the left of its current routing, then make the connections to C7 and C11 on the opposite sides. In other words, flip C11 and C7. From the regulator, run +12 diagonally to C7, then vertically to C11, then diagonally to the existing 12V line.

And beef up your ground trace as much as you can. If you're worrying about the relative attenuation of the bypass caps (the usual reason for using several different-value caps in parallel), you're worrying about high-frequency response, and you need to think about minimizing the impedance of the ground trace. Like I say, a ground plane is the way to go, but if you can't do that, make the ground traces just as wide as you can, and avoid serpentine ground traces. Try to add some traces to turn your ground trace into a grid.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the device off the bottom right of your picture is a voltage regulator - if so, GND must be routed that way to make the reqired connections.

There may be something off to the left that requires the GND track to be above the +12V track.

Answer (score 0):

I think a more important question would be regarding the **location** of C6, C7, and C8. I understand that you need a large, probably electrolytic, capacitor at the input and output of the regulator but why are these smaller capacitors there? Do they need to be closer to other components?